# Why does invoking procedure that uses REGEX_SUBSTR through PLSQL code block return an extra '￢' char?

Tags: sql, regex, plsql, regex-group

Editing in PLSQL.

I've got the following procedure:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE StringTest(StringToTest IN varchar2) 
AS
   result varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    result := REGEXP_SUBSTR(StringToTest, '[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}\/?\s?\w*(\/\d{4})?',1,1);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Result is ' || result);

END;
/
```

The purpose of this procedure is to take in a string, match it with the regex, and then return the first match in the string.  I understand for this example the regex is more complicated than it needs to be, but that is because I have truncated the code to its simplest form.  The actual code is much more complex, and therefore the regex looks more complex than it needs to for this example.

When I invoke the procedure through a PLSQL code block such as

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
   String1 varchar2(100);
BEGIN
   String1 := '(‘Hello’)';
   StringTest(String1);   
END;
/
```

I get the following:

```
Result is Hello￢
```

When I invoke the procedure through an EXEC statement such as

```
EXEC StringTest('(‘Hello’)');
```

I get the following

```
Result is Hello
```

The second result is what I expect in both cases.  My question is, why does invoking the same exact procedure through a PLSQL code block add the extra `￢` character to the output?

Comment: Interesting. I get `Result is Hello`  after  running each of those code block in   both SQLcl and latest SQL developer version under Oracle 12.2. But, SQL * Plus and  [dbfiddle for 11g](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=31815a1f3d3c6175d78c5ee5c3322dce) gives me something else. Same for [18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=31815a1f3d3c6175d78c5ee5c3322dce). So, it's quite likely something to do the tool/editor that  is parsing   PL/SQL or displaying the results.

Comment: I concur with @KaushikNayak. The basic REGEXP_SUBSTR executes as expected in both Oracle 11.2 and Oracle 18; thus, there's something else going on which the posted code doesn't demonstrate. Also - when posting your code you apparently used a word processor to do some editing, which is demonstrated by the fact that the "single quote" characters around `Hello` are not really apostrophes. Don't use a word processor to edit code! :-)

Comment: Have you checked the match result after dropping the right single apostrophe? Obviously different interpretations of character encodings conspire to the effect. What really happens depends on db settings and all other tools involved, in particular the tools that take the code snippets to the server (eg. sqlplus). To investigate further, add the line `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('string1 in hex: ' || UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(string1));` to your code block to figure which octet sequence the regexp command is actually operating on.